# Error installing MySQLdb with pipenv on Ubuntu 23

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pipenv

What is wrong here, at first it was installing then, errors.

```
(AirBnB_clone_v3) genius:AirBnB_clone_v3(storage_get_count) ₦ sudo pipenv install --dev MySQLdb
Installing MySQLdb...
Resolving MySQLdb...
Added mysqldb to Pipfile's [dev-packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
...
✔ Success!
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠇ Locking...False
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqldb (from versions: none)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
...
...
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 728, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
(AirBnB_clone_v3) genius:AirBnB_clone_v3(storage_get_count) ₦
```

Before using `sudo` and `--dev`, I already tried `pipenv install MySQLdb` but nothing seems to change.

I also have `libmysqlclient-dev` installed with `pipenv`